# REST (JSON) - Check if a date is between two dates

Tags: json, rest, date, url, jira

I need to be returned by a REST, all jira sprints that are between a date. To be more precise I need the Json that is returned by REST to be filtered as follows.

> Sprint.completedDate> = StartDate and Sprint.completedDate <= EndDate

I need a rest call that returns what I want.

I am using this REST -> ... / rest / agile / 1.0 / board / 280 / sprint

```
{  
   "maxResults":50,
   "startAt":0,
   "isLast":true,
   "values":[  
      {  
         "id":293,
         "self":".../rest/agile/1.0/sprint/293",
         "state":"closed",
         "name":"AFCOD_TE Sprint 1",
         "startDate":"2019-07-01T17:59:12.209Z",
         "endDate":"2019-07-15T17:59:00.000Z",
         "completeDate":"2019-07-30T18:01:53.539Z",
         "originBoardId":280,
         "goal":""
      },
      {  
         "id":294,
         "self":".../rest/agile/1.0/sprint/294",
         "state":"closed",
         "name":"AFCOD_TE Sprint 2",
         "startDate":"2019-07-15T18:00:38.093Z",
         "endDate":"2019-07-31T18:00:00.000Z",
         "completeDate":"2019-07-31T08:33:37.265Z",
         "originBoardId":280,
         "goal":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I just need to filter the completed date by two dates that I pass as a parameter in the REST call.

Best Regards

Comment: What is the code you have so far? What have you tried and where are you stuck? We won't just write the whole algorithm for you

Comment: Why not retrieve all sprints and `.filter(s=>Date(s['completedDate'])>Date('now'))`?

Comment: I'm not asking for a whole algorithm. Just would like to know how to do the comparison to filter on the REST call. Filter the JSON. Can this be done on the REST call via the URL? It's possible?  Regarding bringing all the Sprints and filtering on my side. It's possible but I would like to do this on the server side.